# Ranorex, unable to bound variables and data source

Tags: ranorex

I'm trying to use **data driven testing** with **Ranorex** ([Ranorex user guide](https://www.ranorex.com/help/latest/ranorex-studio-advanced/data-driven-testing/introduction/))

I have a simple data connector

[image: data source creation]

The variables I've created from the recording module are automatically available from the "Bind parameters to variables section".

However I can't **bind the data source to variables**...

[image: Data source - data binding]

**How to create these variables ?**

Thanks for your help !

*Note that I'm using Ranorex 9.3.4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, **data binding is working if I define the data source on a "Smart Folder" object** (2).

*Note that I still don't know why it does not work with "Test case" object (1)*

[image: data binding works fine with smart folder]

Comment: It does also work when you define the data source in the test case. I just tried it by myself. When you look at the second screenshot in your question, you bound the variables of the record module to parameters defined in the test suite. Therefore, you are not able to bind the variables to the data source. 

So remove the two parameters in the lower panel, then you will be able to bind the variables to your data source in the upper panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the variables in the testcase and keep the same names as in the simple data connector, then the Auto-Bind function in the data binding will work too.